# Cakephp 3 unit test unable to post data

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I run an api using postman, it works. But my unit tests that I create for it doesn't work

Below is my unit test file

```
<?php
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Controller\Api;

use App\Controller\Api\EmployeesController;
use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase;

/**
 * App\Controller\Api\EmployeesController Test Case
 */
class EmployeesApiControllerTest extends IntegrationTestCase
{

    /**
     * Fixtures
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $fixtures = [
        'app.projects',
        'app.projects_sites',
        'app.transactions',
        'app.sites'
    ];

    /**
    * Test REST API PIN login
    */

    public function testJwtToken() {
      $this->configRequest([
          'headers' => [
              'Accept' => 'application/json',
              'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
          ]
      ]);
      $this->post('/api/employees/token', ['pin_code' => '1001']);
      $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
}
```

And this is the console response after running it

```
$ docker-compose run webapp vendor/bin/phpunit tests/TestCase/Controller/Api/EmployeesApiControllerTest.php 
Starting timesheetcakephp_mysql_1 ... done
PHPUnit 6.5.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 1.52 seconds, Memory: 6.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) App\Test\TestCase\Controller\Api\EmployeesApiControllerTest::testJwtToken
Status code is not between 200 and 204
Failed asserting that 500 is equal to 204 or is less than 204.

/var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/IntegrationTestCase.php:796
/var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/IntegrationTestCase.php:713
/var/www/html/tests/TestCase/Controller/Api/EmployeesApiControllerTest.php:37

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 4, Failures: 1.
```

The debug log keeps showing this

```
2018-03-29 19:47:13 Debug: duration=0 rows=0 SELECT Employees.id AS `Employees__id`, Employees.project_id AS `Employees__project_id`, Employees.name AS `Employees__name` FROM employees Employees WHERE Employees.pin_code = NULL LIMIT 1
```

I don't understand why the pin_code keep stating as NULL when I have clearly stated in my unit test to be '1001'.

Comment: `500` means there's an error... check your logs, and if you cannot solve the problem with the info provided there, please post it here (error message and stack strace) and also show what the related controller/action looks like.

Comment: ok i know why. Apparently it is the `'Content-Type' => 'application/json'` that is causing the issue